# In lichen, do the fungi consume the oxygen produced by algae?

Tags: mycology, respiration, symbiosis, algae

Is the oxygen produced by algae in photosynthesis consumed by the fungi, specifically in marine lichens where oxygen is less abundant? I am wondering this because of a speculative evolution project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exchange of gases between lichen symbionts has been demonstrated for *Flavoparmelia caperata*. Note that this is a [foliose lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliose_lichen) species, though the findings may be generalizable to marine lichen.

> We discovered the first evidence that photosynthetic O<sub>2</sub> and respiratory CO<sub>2</sub> mutually power the lichen symbiosis, together with the previously recognized exchange of Calvin-cycle sugars and water.

Ten Veldhuis MC, Ananyev G, Dismukes GC. [Symbiosis extended: exchange of photosynthetic O<sub>2</sub> and fungal-respired CO<sub>2</sub> mutually power metabolism of lichen symbionts.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31893333/) *Photosynth Res*. 2020 Mar;143(3):287-299.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful

Comment: @katzenklavier if mine was indeed a helpful answer, I would appreciate if it was accepted. Seeing no other answers in the weeks since this was posted, I think this is reasonable.

Comment: done, sorry, I'm not to knowledgeable about this site